# How to dispose instance of Background Audio Player in WP8.1 Silver Light App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app in WP8.1 silverlight in which in a case it is necessary to kill instance of background audio player because in this case i am using currently played song for other purpose .
How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try calling `NotifyComplete`? That should kill the BAP instance.

Comment: I read that BAP does not exist in WP8.1 SL, first tell me hoe can i get BAP class in WP8.1 SilverLight

Comment: So what did you try and why it's not working out?

Comment: I am simply asking how to access Background Audio Player using C# in WP8.1(Silver Light).

Answer (score 0):

> The AudioPlayerAgent and AudioStreamingAgent classes, which supported background audio playback for Windows Phone 8 apps, are not supported in Silverlight 8.1. If you want to support background audio playback, you can continue to use a Windows Phone 8 app or create a Windows Phone Store app, which supports new background audio APIs.

Source: [Platform compatibility and breaking changes for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642084(v=vs.105).aspx)